# Filter Firebase query with array?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm creating a simple Tinder clone to learn Firebase and I'm not sure how to add a filter to this Firebase query (I'm using GeoFire to search within a radius):

```
//get closest user for next game within radius
let center = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
var circleQuery = geoFire.query(at: center, withRadius: 149.0)

var queryHandle = circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
    print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
```

I need to filter out users that the current user already accepted/rejected. I could add an array for current user that contains accepted/rejected users, but I'm worried that iterating through an array each time a child is returned in the query could eat up a lot of data.

Comment: There is no simple way to add additional conditions to a GeoFire query. You will have to do the filtering of the additional conditions in your client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have that array of matches/rejections. You could potentially store an array inside the user object for rejections and matches, but you'd need to make use of the firebase security rules just so you are being selective about what data you're exposing to a user that has a list of matched/rejected user ids.

You'll also end up with somewhat duplicated data, due to the accepted lists being stored in both users user objects, but that is the nature of firebase. Doing it this way won't cause any performance hangups or anything.

If you were to do it the way i've suggested here, when you create your list of user cards to swipe through, you would simply use a wildcard (Firebase technically doesn't support wildcards but their documentation explains a way around this) for the user ID, and then set where your current users ID is not found in the potential matches rejected array. I've linked the docs on filtering just as a reference.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data